# Can I install the TurtleBot SDK on Mac?

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now I have to run a virtualbox ubuntu in my Mac,
Can I install TurtleBot SDK on Mac?

Thanks.

And If iphone can control TurtleBot , It will be cool.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11368/can-i-install-the-turtlebot-sdk-on-mac?/) by [jeffkyjin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1141/jeffkyjin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure if the TurtleBot SDK will work on the Mac, but I have been working on ROS support for the Mac and you could follow my instructions here: <s>https://github.com/wjwwood/ros-osx/tree/master/electric-lion-homebrew</s> http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/OSX/Homebrew

Once you get the basics of ROS installed on your Mac you can give the TurtleBot SDK a whirl.

If you want to "drive" your turtlebot with your iPhone, Michael Carroll is working on an general OSC client for ROS which we have used in the past with the TouchOSC iPhone app to drive our robots.

TouchOSC: http://hexler.net/software/touchosc

rososc: <s>https://github.com/mjcarroll/mcarroll-ros-pkg/tree/master/rososc</s>

https://github.com/Auburn-Automow/rososc

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2011-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1